# How come no-one has bug bites on Dagobah?

Tags: star-wars, the-empire-strikes-back, return-of-the-jedi, animals

Yoda doesn’t even have a screen door to keep the bugs out. And we do see some bugs on Dagobah.

Can the Force be used as bug repellent, and was it? Can lightsabers double as bug zappers? What is really going on here?

Comment: Maybe there are no biting insects? This is not our universe after all....

Comment: Assuming there even were biting insects, Luke and Yoda were aliens on their planet. They would not have evolved to feed on them or recognize them as food.

Comment: If anyone has an example of a lightsaber being used as a bug zapper, please post it here: http://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/147189/75000

Comment: Something something the power of the Force

Comment: Come on.  In Star Wars, you see non-native species trying to eat each other all the time, like the sand worm thingy

Comment: I think slapping away bugs every 5 seconds might well have turned the movie into a 3 Stooges skit.

Comment: Different critters have evolved different ways of identifying prey, smell and temperature are frequently important to biting insects on our world, larger predators use visual, aural, and scent cues.

Comment: The creatures of dagoba feast upon your soul, not your blood

Comment: @sonofsam. Not canon, but there's a bit on that in the Family Guy's take on the Original Trilogy.

Comment: @Paul If you can post an answer with a pic, I promise to upvote it. You might get mocked, but I'll laugh.

Comment: @SonofSam done!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It's likely that creatures like the insect-eating [Sleen](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Sleen) (seen in Star Wars: The Empire Strikes Back) do an excellent job of keeping the swamps clear of biting insects.

[image: The Sleen, a greenish-gray lizard-like creature]

We know that there are both insects and insectivores in and around Yoda's hut (courtesy of "[Meet the Creatures of Dagobah](http://www.starwars.com/news/meet-the-creatures-of-dagobah)") and we know that larger animals are attracted by his Force-essence and tendency to provide shelter to non-carnivorous species.

> ...being so close to the lagoon, with open doors and windows, means
> Yoda's home is visited by many creatures. Yoda frequently finds
> snakes, lizards, butcherbugs and spiny bograts scampering across the
> floor. He doesn't mind the company and only sweeps the venomous ones
> back out the door.
>
> <sub><sup>[Ultimate Star Wars](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Ultimate_Star_Wars)</sup></sub>

The book also makes note that when he was still living in the E3 escape pod, he was subject to frequent attacks from

> *persistent pests*

but these seem to have stopped when he moved into his hut, presumably as a result of sharing his living space with numerous insectivores.

Comment: Although it could be said that over reliance on green screen technology caused an unforgivable omission.